# Issue using IF statements within a MySQL INSERT Trigger

Tags: mysql

For a uni assignment, I need to make a trigger that sets salary to a specified value if it's less than 50,000 when a new employee row is inserted into the table. Currently what I'm trying is

```
CREATE TRIGGER empSalInsert
BEFORE INSERT ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
IF (NEW.salary <50000) THEN
    SET NEW.salary = 0
END IF;
```

But that gives the error

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 6
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1064
```

I've tried to fix the issue by both adding a semicolon after SET NEW.salary = 0 like so,

```
CREATE TRIGGER empSalInsert
BEFORE INSERT ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
IF (NEW.salary <50000) THEN
    SET NEW.salary = 0;
END IF;
```

But then the error becomes

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1064
Error occurred in:
CREATE TRIGGER empSalInsert
BEFORE INSERT ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
IF (NEW.salary <50000) THEN
    SET NEW.salary = 0
```

I've also tried removing END IF all together,

```
CREATE TRIGGER empSalInsert
BEFORE INSERT ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
IF (NEW.salary <50000) THEN
    SET NEW.salary = 0;
```

Which just spits out a similar error

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1064
```

Anyone know what's going on?
I'm using SQuirrel if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `DELIMITER`so that mysql knows what belongs to the trigger

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER empSalInsert
BEFORE INSERT ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.salary <50000) THEN
        SET NEW.salary = 0;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That creates the error
`Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER empSalInsert
BEFORE INSERT ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
IF (N' at line 1
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1064
Error occurred in:
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER empSalInsert
BEFORE INSERT ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
IF (NEW.salary <50000) THEN
    SET NEW.salary = 0`

Comment: sorry i forgot the`BEGIN`and `END` ple4ase try again

Comment: Same error, I'm starting to think there might be an issue on my computer deeper than just the code.

Comment: as you can chdck here this works https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3SpLAoG55wrEdnCisvYbrK/8

Comment: Perfect, the code works on that site! I'll just have to figure out what's going on with my computer later.